# Setting up 2 virtual hosts in nginx in a docker container and address them via hostname

Tags: networking, nginx, linux-networking, docker, hostname

I searched already but I am not quite sure if the questions I found cover my problem.

I have a virtual machine (ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS) which has docker already installed and a nginx webserver running (works fine).

Not I want to set up a second virtual host.
For that I have one configuration file szenario.conf which contains the following lines:[1. host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyf70.png) and [2. host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDjKQ.png)

The docker-compose.yml looks like this:[Docker compose yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Byr.png)

Now whenever I enter the IP of the Virtual machine, I have to type for example 192.168.56.103:8080 which only returns the first website (speedo in this example).

Typing example.speedo and example.fakebook are routed into the internet and dont work.

How do I make both sites available via hostname so that when i export this machine, another user can easily access these sites by typing the names when importing the machine in his enviroment?

What changes do I have to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To type in a hostname in the address bar of your browser and have the browser connect to your virtual machine, it has to resolve the hostname to an IP address. To do so it first looks in a file `/etc/hosts` and checks if the hostname is defined there. If it is, the IP specified in the file is used. If not, a regular DNS lookup is performed.

Depending on your environment you might not be able to change DNS, so let's first concentrate on `etc/hosts` (or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` if your OS is windows). This is a file local to your computer, so any changes you make there only influence your own browser.

To be able to open "example.speedo" and "example.fakebook" in your browser and connect to your nginx, append the following line to your hosts file:

```
192.168.56.103 example.speedo example.fakebook
```

All it does is telling your computer, that the names "example.speedo" and "example.fakebook" should be resolved to "192.168.56.103".

Please be aware while this works for you, if you give your virtual machine to someone else, they have to do the same modification to their hosts file.

The other option would be to change your DNS. As the process of doing so depends heavily on the used DNS server I cannot tell how to do it. You would have to add two new zones, speedo and facebook and add the DNS entries there. Then other users using the same DNS server (that probably means being on the same network as you) could use your machine without having to edit their hosts file.

However, I can not recommend this, as creating fake zones in a local DNS server using names that might one day be offical zones (it is possible that facebook registeres the TLD facebook) can lead to problems in the future (in this case facebook might stop working some day for you).

If you use a domain you own or that may be used locally (e.g. "local") you can add Names below this domain without worries. Examples would be "speedo.local" and "facebook.local" or "speedo.your.name.here" and "facebook.your.name.here".

To not have to specify the port in the address bar, you should have nginx on port 80 instead of 8080. Set `ports` to `80:80` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the virtual host names to `/etc/hosts` on the computer which will be used to access those hosts.

So, if you run the browser on your host and want to access site in a container, you need to add the following lines to your `/etc/hosts` file on your host:

```
192.168.56.103 example.speedo
192.168.56.103 example.fakebook
```

If your host is a Windows machine, you need to enter those lines in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' file.

An alternative would be add those to a DNS zone for your domains.